# How does a bin folder that is excluded from a project affect automated builds?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, nant

We do automated builds using Nant and CruiseControl.net. I'm very green when it comes to the process. While looking into some things, I noticed that for most(all?) of the solutions involved in the automated build process, the bin folders are included in the project. Is this a requirement for automated builds? If the bin folder is excluded, will the folder and any files in it need to be copied to the deployment servers manually?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are referring to the /bin/debug/ folder under a project, you should not need those checked into your source control.  If you have external libraries (log4net.dll for example) they should be checked into source control along with your code, but in a separate folder (named "ThirdParty" or "DLLs" for example.)  When CruiseControl.net runs, it should compile any assemblies that have been modified, and copy output to the /bin/debug/ folder in the same way as VisualStudio copies those files on your box.

Comment: As a matter of princip you should never vesion files that are built automatically by the build process. Except your project dependencies, the bin/Debug and bin/Release are part of these files.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to include bin folder in the automated build process, since it contains some external dlls like AjaxControlToolkit along with internal dlls.

We here excluded the Debug folder and user option files(*.suo) from the automated build.